# std::bind a member function to an instance at nullptr causing seemingly random this pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior

I've tested the following program on gcc-4.8 (via Coliru) and on Visual Studio 2013 RC:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    void bar() {
        cout << "this = " << this << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        foo *ptr = nullptr;
        function<void ()> fun = bind(&foo::bar, *ptr);
        fun();
    } catch (const bad_function_call &e) {
        // never reached
        cout << "bad_function_call thrown: " << e.what() << endl;
    } 

    cin.get();
}
```

I understand I'm causing undefined behavior here by dereferencing nullptr, but I don't understand the output of my code. In my understanding this should either cause a bad_function_call (because that is what should be thrown when calling this std::function, from what I guessed) or at least print "this = 0".

It doesn't. The output is "this = " followed by some pointer which is not nullptr on both compilers I tested. Accessing it causes a segmentation fault, though.

Is there a clause in the standard specifying this? Or is it just implementation-defined "undefined behavior"?

Edit: Just as an addition: The following code outputs "this = 0" on my machine:

```
foo *ptr = nullptr;
ptr->bar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that `bind` stores a copy of the argument. The argument is of type `foo` (since you are passing `*ptr`) and hence a copy is made. The copy, of course, gets an invalid argument as source, but that is not used and hence this seems to work. As a result, a new instance of `foo` is stored inside the bound object and this is the address you see.

When you say you see a segmentation fault, you refer to your real code, not the example you gave here, right? In your real code I guess the copy-ctor seems to work but creates an instance which causes the segmentation fault when you access its (probably invalid) members.

Comment: So passing ref(*foo) should cause "this = 0" to be the output then? Going to do some tests. Edit: It does.

Comment: The segmentation fault was about accessing this in foo::bar. I was wondering why it did not throw std::bad_function_call, because that would make sense IMHO.

Comment: @DominikLohmann `bad_function_call` is reserved for when the function pointer itself is `0`, but you are passing a valid member function pointer. You are just not passing in a valid instance as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined" means undefined. Reasoning about what happens when you have undefined behavior is futile unless your compiler documents what it does.

Comment: Whilst I agree with you in terms of the Standard, in terms of a specific implementation it can be interesting to understand why something works (even if bizarre).

Comment: @MatthieuM. - "interesting" does not negate "futile". `<g>`

Comment: *All knowledge is worth having* -- Anafiel Delaunay